# How to send Spinner item value to multiple subscibers using Rxbinding

Tags: android-studio, rx-java, android-spinner, rx-java2, rx-binding

Android :

What I've implemented till now is, get spinner value to the immediate subscriber using itemSelection(). 
Code :

```
    Observavle observavle = RxAdapterView.itemSelections(spinner);
    observable.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(integer -> {
    Log.v("spinner", integer.toString());
    });
```

What I want to achieve is :

I want to subscribe multiple observers to this Observable.
For which I have created few Observers and used

```
    Observable.subscribe(observer1);
    Observable.subscribe(observer2);
    Observable.subscribe(few more observers);
```

To get spinner updated value on these observers, but this is not working,
OnNext() of these observers won't get called on spinner value change.

(Note: This situation works perfectly in case of RxBinding Textview using on textchange() ).

Will surely upvote if you can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `share()` operator:

```
Observavle observavle = RxAdapterView.itemSelections(spinner).share();
```

You can read more about `share()` in this [blog post.](https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-use-rxjava-share-operator-26b08973771a)